# how to center lstlisting with escapeinside

Tags: listings

I wish to center a code listing with some latex math symbols in there (such as **\forall**). Unfortunately it causes my listing to get shifted towards the right.  It now centers the left edge of the listing instead of the center of the listing.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}{
            \begin{lstlisting}[language=customLanguage]
{
    %*$\forall formula here $*)
    %*$\forall second formula here $*) 
}\end{lstlisting}
    }\end{tabular}
    \caption{my caption.}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

This is the result: [image: Shifted to the right]

However!  If I remove the \escapeinside syntax to run Latex code, like so:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}{
            \begin{lstlisting}[language=customLanguage]
{
    \forall formula here $*)
    %*$\forall second formula here $*) 
}\end{lstlisting}
    }\end{tabular}
    \caption{my caption.}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

Then I get the correct positioning, but obviously not the intended text: [image]

Any way I can have my cake and eat it too?

My .sty file:

```
% Define IDP
\lstdefinelanguage{customLanguage}{
    ... % irrelevant stuff
}
\lstset{
    language=customLanguage,
    tabsize=3,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,  
    %frame=none,
    %frame=single,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines = true,
    alsoletter=(,
    commentstyle=\commentstyle,
    keywordstyle=[1],
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{BrickRed}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{OliveGreen}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[4]\color{Blue}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[5]\color{Violet}\bfseries,
    literate={~} {$\sim$}{1}
}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

Comment: Please, make the code snippets into a full document.

Comment: putting a listing with more than one line in a c-type tabular cell is quite daring ..